# Getting 401 Unauthorized during Gradle build for Atlassian Renderer library

Tags: spring, gradle, build.gradle, mvn-repo

I think by Gradle build problem is related to this Spring [article](https://spring.io/blog/2020/10/29/notice-of-permissions-changes-to-repo-spring-io-fall-and-winter-2020) about Spring Artifactory instance repo.spring.io permissions. Pls help me correct my build.gradle which has started failing recently after upgrading to Gradle 5.0.

Snippet from build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = SPRING_BOOT_VERSION
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone'
        }
    
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath('se.transmode.gradle:gradle-docker:1.2')
    }
}
apply plugin: 'java'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone'
    }
    maven { url "https://packages.atlassian.com/maven/repository/public" }
}

dependencies {
    compile (group: 'com.atlassian.renderer', name: 'atlassian-renderer', version:'8.0.5') {
        exclude(module: 'servlet-api')
        exclude(module: 'radeox')
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation
        compile group: 'javax.activation', name: 'activation', version: '1.1.1'

    }
}
```

The error i get is

```
      > Could not resolve com.atlassian.renderer:atlassian-renderer:8.0.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/com/atlassian/renderer/atlassian-renderer/8.0.5/atlassian-renderer-8.0.5.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/com/atlassian/renderer/atlassian-renderer/8.0.5/atlassian-renderer-8.0.5.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I added jCenter in the repositories in build.gradle and it worked for me.

```
    jcenter()
```

I think the atlassian-renderer is no longer available with maven repo.